Eigenfunctions of self-adjoint compact operator on (cartesian) product Hilbert space
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and consider the cartesian product $H^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $T$ be a compact self-adjoint operator on $H^m$. Is it true that each eigenfunction of $T$ can be written either as $(f_{k_1},0,...,0)$, or $(0,f_{k_2},0,...,0)$, or ..., or $ (0,...,0,f_{k_m})$ (please excuse this notational abuse, I am not sure how to formulate this properly) where $\{f_n\}_n$ is an ON-set in $H$?

Take $m=2$, choose a non-zero $f\in H$, and consider $T$ = the orthogonal projection to the 1-dim space given by $(f,f)$.

Ah, yes that is a counter-example. You can post this as an answer if you'd like.
